# On pressed back in android Webview how to go back to previous task instead of closing app?

Tags: android, android-activity, webview, back-button, back-stack

I have an webview app having a MainActivity which is load the website and another one is Bookmark Activity/List. There is a button in the MainActivity to open the bookmark list.

After opening bookmark list when user click on a link from that list, it will open/load in MainActivity.

**The problem is**,
After opening a link from Bookmark list, when user press back button, it's showing app closing warning dialogue. 
The code i used is...

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    if(MyWebview.canGoBack()){
        MyWebview.goBack();
    }else{
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                .setTitle("Exit!")
                .setMessage("Are you sure to close?")
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        finish();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                .show();
    }
}
```

**What I want,** 
After opening a link from Bookmark list, after pressing back button, it will show the Bookmark list instead of showing app closing warning dialogue.
Like this...

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    if(MyWebview.canGoBack()){
        MyWebview.goBack();
    }else{

        // If bookmark list is open in Back Stack, go to Bookmark List,
       // and if Bookmark List is not open, show the app closing warning dialogue. 

}
```

Comment: Please show the code you use to open the link from the bookmark list.

Answer (score 0):

```
   @Override
  public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
    switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
            if (mWebView.canGoBack()) {
                mWebView.goBack();
            } else {
                show dialog();
            }
            return true;
    }

}
return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
  }
```

Comment: mWebView is your webview object

Comment: I have run my sample on activity class its working fine when we press on back button.

Comment: remove  backpress method if your are using this.